# My Rest service won't work in Tomcat and I can't get it to send my resource, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: web-services, rest, tomcat, jersey

So I started to read [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-tomcat/) tutorial about how to develop a Restful service with Jersey. I  want to develop Rest service that sends the data from a MySQL database to an Android client. I read and followed the steps on the tutorial and made my own resource classes, but when I tried to run the service on Apache I got the following error [here](http://pastebin.com/cGeNMrCH).

I'm just starting to experiment with web services and Rest, I have read the information related to the subject from that IBM site and I thought I got the hang of it, but I'm really lost as to why is not working.

My web.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>TesterRest</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.mx.ipn.escom.testerRest.resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

This is my resource class:

package com.mx.ipn.escom.testerRest.resources;

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Request;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import com.mx.ipn.escom.testerRest.dao.TemaDao;
import com.mx.ipn.escom.testerRest.db.Connector;
import com.mx.ipn.escom.testerRest.modelo.Tema;

@XmlRootElement
@Path("/temas")
public class TemaResource {
    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;
    @Context
    Request request;

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public List<Tema> getTemas() throws SQLException{

        TemaDao temaDao = new TemaDao();        
        List<Tema> temas=temaDao.getTemas();
        temaDao.terminarSesion();

        return temas;
    }
}
```

My class for database connection works fine, so that one isn't the problem.

I'm using Eclipse 3.6 to develop and Apache Tomcat 6.

I'm completely new to JAXB, so if anyone can give me guidelines to what kind of annotations am I missing I would appreciate it.

Comment: Are you certain that `TemaResource` is in the package `com.ipn.escom.testerRest.resources`? This looks like it should work otherwise...

Comment: it is, here's a screenshot of my packages http://tinypic.com/r/6rluh1/6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your screenshot I think you should update your web.xml to have the correct package name:

```xml
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.mx.ipn.escom.testerRest.resources</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

The `mx` is missing from your configuration.

Comment: I added the mx, but then I got a HTTP 500 error, I'm trying to access with this url http://localhost:8080/TesterRest/rest/temas, I don't understand what's missing. In theory I should get a JSON output when I access the localhost url. This is the output from tomcat http://pastebin.com/94LXYv4z an error is thrown at line 31.

Comment: The main problem here is: `GRAVE: A message body writer for Java type, class java.util.ArrayList, and MIME media type, application/xml, was not found`. You need to make sure that the `Tema` bean has correct JAXB annotations - in particular `@XmlRootElement`. And if you want JSON you should change your `@Produces` annotation to list the JSON before the XML or change your client code to request JSON.

Comment: this is my TemaResource class http://pastebin.com/Bfb7fmS7, at the moment I'm only aiming to retrieve a List with Tema objects, can you tell me which annotations am I missing? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You don't want `@XmlRootElement` on your `TemaResource` - you want it on the class that you're going to serialize - in this case `Tema`.

Comment: this is how I have my `Tema` model class http://pastebin.com/WKRpgRrY and after adding the `@XmlRootElement` now I got this error http://pastebin.com/JfjQAFxS from what it says there's a problem with me using an ArrayList in my `TemaDao` class http://pastebin.com/DBhV4vuw

Comment: I don't think the `ArrayList` is the problem - it's that you don't have a no argument constructor for `Tema`. So just add `Tema() {}` next to your public constructor and try it again...

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly, I got a JSON output, thanks for all your help, any other things you can address me? I'm new using JAXB so if you can redirect me to more info in annotations I must consider or stuff like that I would appreciate it so much.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.vogella.com/articles/JAXB/article.html about basic JAXB and I found the Jersey documentation to be pretty good. http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html